# Javascript array of object add conditional value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My Array of object is below

```
 var filterStatus = [{ doc_count: 49, key: "Completed", color: "#1DC9B7" }, { doc_count: 147, key: "Failed", color: "#F14C69" }, { doc_count: 321, key: "In Progress", color: "#FFC568" }, { doc_count: 29, key: "Started" }];
```

I want to get result which contains Completed, Failed and In progress (Should Contains Started) status

I am trying below code

```
var result = filterStatus.filter(obj => { if(obj.key == 'Started' || obj.key == 'In Progress'){ return obj}} ).map(obj => obj.doc_count).reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
```

and i am getting result 350

**My expected output is**

```
[{ doc_count: 49, key: "Completed", color: "#1DC9B7" }, { doc_count: 147, key: "Failed", color: "#F14C69" }, { doc_count: 350, key: "In Progress", color: "#FFC568" }];
```

**Note:** Expected output contains addition of Started and In progress inside In Progress doc_count.

Comment: `reduce()` turns an array into a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const filterStatus = [{ doc_count: 49, key: "Completed", color: "#1DC9B7" }, { doc_count: 147, key: "Failed", color: "#F14C69" }, { doc_count: 321, key: "In Progress", color: "#FFC568" }, { doc_count: 29, key: "Started" }];
// filter out "Started"
const result = filterStatus.filter(({key}) => key !== "Started");
// find and update "In Progress"
result.find(({key}) => key === "In Progress").doc_count += filterStatus.find(({key}) => key === "Started").doc_count;
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce and map seperately

```js
var filterStatus = [{
  doc_count: 49,
  key: "Completed",
  color: "#1DC9B7"
}, {
  doc_count: 147,
  key: "Failed",
  color: "#F14C69"
}, {
  doc_count: 321,
  key: "In Progress",
  color: "#FFC568"
}, {
  doc_count: 29,
  key: "Started"
}];
 var val=filterStatus.map(function(e){
  if(e.key=="In Progress" || e.key=="Started")
  return e.doc_count
  else
  return 0}).reduce(function(acc,e){return acc+=e},0)
var result = filterStatus.filter(function(obj) {
if(obj.key == 'In Progress')
obj.doc_count=val;
      if (obj.key == 'Completed' || obj.key == 'In Progress' || obj.key == 'Failed')
        return obj;
    })
   console.log(result)
```

Comment: Result is different from what OP expected

Comment: Still different from expectations

Answer (score -1):

```
var filterStatus = [{ doc_count: 49, key: "Completed", color: "#1DC9B7" }, { doc_count: 147, key: "Failed", color: "#F14C69" }, { doc_count: 321, key: "In Progress", color: "#FFC568" }, { doc_count: 29, key: "Started" }];


function mergeInProgressStarted () {
 return filterStatus.filter(({key}) => {
   return ['In Progress', 'Started'].indexOf(key) > -1;
}).reduce((acc, status) => {
  acc.doc_count += status.doc_count;
  if (status.color) {
    acc.color = status.color;
  } 
  return acc;
  }, { key: "In Progress", doc_count: 0 })
}



filterStatus.filter(({ key  }) => ['Completed', 'Failed'].indexOf(key) > -1).concat([mergeInProgressStarted()])
```

Comment: Result is different from what OP expected